# Como posso fazer o usuario definir quantas vezes vai usar uma função em python?

Tags: python

```
def novo(numeros):
    import random
    numeros = []    
    while(len(numeros) < 10):
        num = random.randint(1,20)
        if (not num in numeros):
            numeros.append(num)
    return numeros
```

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários. Aproveite e veja [ask] e faça o nosso [tour].

Answer (score -3):

```
from random import randint

def novo():
    x = int(input("Selecione o número de vezes que pretende utilizar a função"))
    i = 0      
    numeros = [] 
    while i <= x:
        num= randint(1,20)
        
        if num not in numeros:
            numeros.append(num)
        print(num)
        i += 1           
    return(numeros)
```

Comment: Será isto que pretendes obter?

Comment: Veja [answer] e faça o nosso [tour].